# Why is the c.vim plugin not working?

Tags: plugin-c.vim

I have just tried to install c.vim from this [URL](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213). The only issue is I do not think it is working. This is because I cannot view the help by doing `:help csupport`. How would I fix this?

If it helps here is my `.vim` tree.

```
.vim
├── c-support
│   ├── codesnippets
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── Makefile.multi-target.template
│   │   ├── calloc_double_matrix.c
│   │   ├── calloc_int_matrix.c
│   │   ├── main.c
│   │   ├── main.cc
│   │   ├── print_double_array.c.noindent
│   │   └── print_int_array.c.noindent
│   ├── doc
│   │   ├── ChangeLog
│   │   ├── c-hotkeys.pdf
│   │   └── c-hotkeys.tex
│   ├── rc
│   │   ├── customization.ctags
│   │   ├── customization.gvimrc
│   │   ├── customization.indent.pro
│   │   └── customization.vimrc
│   ├── scripts
│   │   └── wrapper.sh
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── Templates
│   │   ├── c.comments.template
│   │   ├── c.cpp.template
│   │   ├── c.idioms.template
│   │   ├── c.preprocessor.template
│   │   ├── c.statements.template
│   │   ├── cpp.comments.template
│   │   ├── cpp.cpp.template
│   │   ├── cpp.idioms.template
│   │   ├── cpp.preprocessor.template
│   │   └── cpp.statements.template
│   └── wordlists
│       ├── c-c++-keywords.list
│       ├── k+r.list
│       └── stl_index.list
├── doc
│   └── csupport.txt
├── ftplugin
│   └── c.vim
└── plugin
    ├── c.vim
    └── cvim
        ├── README.csupport
        ├── c-support
        │   ├── codesnippets
        │   │   ├── Makefile
        │   │   ├── Makefile.multi-target.template
        │   │   ├── calloc_double_matrix.c
        │   │   ├── calloc_int_matrix.c
        │   │   ├── main.c
        │   │   ├── main.cc
        │   │   ├── print_double_array.c.noindent
        │   │   └── print_int_array.c.noindent
        │   ├── doc
        │   │   ├── ChangeLog
        │   │   ├── c-hotkeys.pdf
        │   │   └── c-hotkeys.tex
        │   ├── rc
        │   │   ├── customization.ctags
        │   │   ├── customization.gvimrc
        │   │   ├── customization.indent.pro
        │   │   └── customization.vimrc
        │   ├── scripts
        │   │   └── wrapper.sh
        │   ├── templates
        │   │   ├── Templates
        │   │   ├── c.comments.template
        │   │   ├── c.cpp.template
        │   │   ├── c.idioms.template
        │   │   ├── c.preprocessor.template
        │   │   ├── c.statements.template
        │   │   ├── cpp.comments.template
        │   │   ├── cpp.cpp.template
        │   │   ├── cpp.idioms.template
        │   │   ├── cpp.preprocessor.template
        │   │   └── cpp.statements.template
        │   └── wordlists
        │       ├── c-c++-keywords.list
        │       ├── k+r.list
        │       └── stl_index.list
        ├── doc
        │   └── csupport.txt
        ├── ftplugin
        │   └── c.vim
        └── plugin
            └── c.vim
```

Also if you need to know this is using vim inside the Mac terminal

Comment: can you plz post your .vimrc file?

Comment: I guess the tag should be more "how do I install plugins" that "plugin-foobar".

Comment: @elyashiv I only had `syntax on` and `set number`. Sorry i'm a bit late to replying! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old way to install plugins is directly within `~/.vim/`, and the doc database was to be updated with `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`. Now, with plugin managers around, we tend to install them into `~/.vim/addons/` or `~/.vim/bundle/` (depending on the plugin manager used).

But it seems you've chosen another place to install your plugin. So, to use it, in your .vimrc, you'll have to fix your runtimepath -> `:set rtp+=~/.vim/c-support`, and you may have to update the doc database as well: `:helptags ~/.vim/c-support/doc`

Comment: It looks like there is actually a `~/.vim/doc/csupport.vim` file, so the first suggestion should be sufficient. There's definitely a lot of litter from this installation, though.

Comment: That's odd. I don't see it (neither in the official zip, nor on the github repo -- I'm not using c-support but another suite for C++ programming, thus this file may be auto-generated which could explain why I don't see it). I see a `<localleader>hp` mapping that builds the help database though.

Comment: Oops, I meant `~/.vim/doc/csupport.txt`. I didn't check the link, but I see it in the directory tree provided in the question.

Comment: Thanks. `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` worked for me!

Comment: Also what is it you use instead of c-support?

Comment: I'm using a suite of several plugins that I'm maintaining (https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp), some being poorly documented. This topic is not the best place to describe my suite.