# Header from Templates not appearing in newly created C source files

Tags: vimrc, snippets

First, I did:

```
% vim ~/.vim/cvim/c-support/templates/Templates
```

From there, I changed my User Macros to their desired values. I then saved my changes.

In Vim, I went to Normal Mode and entered:

```
:!vim test.c
```

However, my header created with User Macros did not appear at the top of the file. I am using http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/tutorial-make-vim-as-your-cc-ide-using-cvim-plugin/ as a reference.

Also, here: https://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-c/csupport.html#csupport-templates, section 5.

I put the following into my .vimrc file:

```
let g:C_Styles = { '.c,.h' : 'C', '.cc,.cpp,.c++,.C,.hh,.h++,*.H' : 'CPP' }
```

However, this did not work, and my heading is not inserted into my newly created C source files.

I know this is a newbie question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*Discl. I'm maintaining an [alternative](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) to c.vim. As such, I don't use it and I don't know its intricacies.*

If you've installed c.vim into `~/.vim/cvim` and if by `% vim ~/.vim/cvim/c-support/templates/Templates` you are editing the original files shipped with the plugin, it's probably a bad idea. Indeed, next time you'll update the plugin, you'll lose all your changes. After a quick survey of the source code though, it seems to be the expected way of using it.

Beside, `~/.vim/cvim` is a really odd place to install a plugin. Are you sure the plugin is working correctly? Reading your question, I'm not sure this is the case. (This reminds me of this Q/A: [Why is the c.vim plugin not working?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/why-is-the-c-vim-plugin-not-working)).

Comment: According to http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213, I am to copy the zip archive to $HOME/.vim/ and then unzip it there.  Is there a better place to unzip it?

Comment: @user3410845, If unzip extracts everything in a subdirectory, then you'll want to add this directory to your runtime path option (`:h 'rtp'`). If the plugin doesn't do/provide anything, then it's likely you either need to change your runtime path option, or to install the plugin directly in `~/.vim` without any intermediary directory -- this is not recommended. Otherwise you can also use a plugin manager which will make the installation almost transparent. (For instance, don't even try to use the alternative lh-cpp without any plugin manager)

Comment: I deleted the plugin and then followed the procedure to copy the zip archive to `$HOME/.vim/` and then unzip it there once more, and now it seems to work fine.  I don't know why it didn't work before.